# ODL with Docker - Web Interface not working

Tags: docker, sdn, opendaylight

I´m new with SDN controllers and I´m trying get start with it, so using Docker on a win10 laptop i tried bring up a container up with ODL Controller image from docker ([glefevre/opendaylight](https://hub.docker.com/r/glefevre/opendaylight/)) hub.

According with the documentation, once its up, it should be reachable on HTTP at http://localhost:8181/index.html and also SSH CLI using port 8101. 
However while SSH 8101 access works fine the HTTP on port 8181 doesn't .

I can see port 8181 is active using netstat

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32> netstat -an | grep 8181
STDIN
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8181           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:8181              [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

The command I used to run the container is

```
docker run -d -p 6633:6633 -p 8181:8181 -p 8101:8101 --name=opendaylight glefevre/opendaylight
```

Any ideas or assistance are welcome

AN

Answer (score 2):

It was missing to install DLUX module

so after get ssh access to karaf ODL console, I had issued the command :

```
feature:install odl-dlux-all
```

And web gui became accessible after that

Comment: just a note: the DLUX project is no longer active and not part of newer OpenDaylight
releases. I think it was removed in the Fluorine release.